# Generating/creating a barcode in Android

Tags: android, barcode

Anyone who knows a good way to generate/create a barcode from a String in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to encode on the device instead of calling to a URL, indeed you want [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing). Look at what it does for the Android client Barcode Scanner in [EncodeActivity](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/EncodeActivity.java).

Comment: It appears that EncodeActivity only encodes QR Codes, but what if I want to display 1D bar-codes in my app, are there any options in ZXing?  I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Google Charts API, a simple call to the following url with your text in `chl` parameter returns an image with the QRcode.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=give+me+a+beer

[image]