# Barcode generating algorithm for android or java

Tags: java, android, generator, barcode

Is there any free java or android barcode (Code128 or upc) generating library for free?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BarCode Image Generator in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java), also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370245/generating-creating-a-barcode-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider usage of [Zxing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). it's qiet open source so you you can find algoritms for generating or reading barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Go through [www.onbarcode.com](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/android_barcode/).. You can get the Barcode Generator ApI

Answer (score 0):

you can search Zxing Barcode Library, ID Automation Barcode Control or Apose Barcode Application, use their free trial package or barcode algorithm to generate barcode java.

[code 128 barcode generator algorithm](http://www.keepdynamic.com/barcoding/java-barcode-generator.shtml) for you